# Can I change the default case for SQL keywords in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

SQL keywords default to upper case in Visual Studio. Is there a way to change that? My team uses lower case for all keywords.

Comment: I've run into this in VS2017. It's happening both in a database project and in the standard editor. I'm also seeing weird things happening sometimes with copy-paste or if I'm in the middle of typing a keyword and then click somewhere else with my mouse.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

In VS2013, go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->SQL Server Tools->Intellisense, and on the right-hand side of the dialog, look for "Casing for built-in function names:" followed by a dropdown offering either Upper or Lower case.

Comment: I tired that and even after restarting Visual Studio it defaults to upper case.

Comment: Same problem with VS 2017